# Extracting String from html using Regular expression

Tags: regex

The following is the html tag:

```
<label lang="en"><span class="color-red f-bold f-left">*</span>Category</label>
```

I want to extract "Category" word to change order using the following Regular expression.

```
(<label\s?\s?lang="en">)\s?\s?(<span\s?\s?class="color-red f-bold (f-left)?">\*<\/span>)+(.)+(<\/label>)
```

above expression successfully finding elements when I want to replace "Category"(groupNo::$4), only getting "y" instead of "Category".
please help me to catch group $4.

Comment: There's a bunch of weirdness in your pattern, but I'm pretty sure the issue you're asking about specifically can be fixed by changing `(.)+` to `(.+)`.

Comment: super bro excellent yes it's absolutely correct. Thanks CAusting